# Stop device camera using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using ngx-webcam package in angular to display webcam. They have not provided any way to stop the camera it just stop when component is destroyed. I have hidden webcam component so that user can't see the webcam. I have tried to stop the webcam using javascript with following code

```
if (this.mediaStream && this.mediaStream.getTracks) {
  this.mediaStream.getTracks().forEach((track: MediaStreamTrack) => {
    track.stop()
  })
}
```

But the indicator light for the webcam does not switch off.

The ngx-webcam package code is as follow

```
component.html

<div class="hidden">
  <webcam [height]="400" [width]="400" [trigger]="triggerObservable" (imageCapture)="handleImage($event)"
    *ngIf="showWebcam" [allowCameraSwitch]="allowCameraSwitch" 
    [switchCamera]="nextWebcamObservable" [imageQuality]="1"
    (initError)="handleInitError($event)" mirrorImage="never">
  </webcam>
</div>
```

```
component.css

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

I have used showWebcam flag to destroy the component.

I am not able to understand if I have done something wrong in the code.

Thank you!

The ngx-webcam package does not have anything specified to stop the webcam. It stops when the component is destroyed. I have used showWebCam flag to destroy the component but it doesn't work. I have also tried by not hidding the component but got same result. I have also tried using javascript and even that didn't work for me.

Comment: Any answer for this question, I also has the same problem